# Lyx 2.0 Formatted references to theorem/lemma/claim environments

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, lyx, theorems

In Lyx 2.0, I'm trying to use a formatted reference to a claim, but I cannot get the "formatted" part, i.e. I can't get it to typeset "claim" as well as the claim number.

I'm using modules "Theorems (Numbered by type)" and "Theorems (Numbered by type within sections)".  I have a paragraph in the "Claim" environment, with a label "claim:1".  (I got the "claim:" part in there by editing `../Resources/layouts/theorems-refprefix.inc`, but I had the same behavior before I made this change.)  I later put in a formatted reference which generates tex code as "`\claimref{1}`".  This typesets to "... 1.1 ..." in the output, i.e. just section and claim counter number.  What I'd like to see is "... claim 1.1 ..."

If I change these claims to theorem environments AND delete and remake the labels (so "thm:1") and update the references, the formatted reference typesets the word "theorem" for the reference, as desired.  Lemma does not seem to work (though I may not have remade all the lables.)

I do see Lyx adding this to the preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\claimref[1]{\ref{claim:#1}}}
```

I also see

```
\RS@ifundefined{thmref}
  {\def\RSthmtxt{theorem~}\newref{thm}{name = \RSthmtxt}}
  {}
```

which I can't trace the origin of, but it may explain why theorem works.

Any ideas?

Comment: The involved package is `refstyle`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to the document preamble (Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble)

```
\newref{claim}{name=claim~}
```

and it will probably work. As mentioned by egreg in the comments, the [`refstyle`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refstyle) package is used, and you have to tell it what it should insert for labels starting with `claim:`.

`refstyle` also provides commands for start-of-sentence references (capital letter) and plural forms, and the words to insert in these cases can also be specified, e.g.

```
\newref{claim}{name=claim~,Name=Claim~,names=claims~,Names=Claims~}
```

I don't know, however, how to make LyX use these, other than through using an ERT, with e.g. `\Claimref{claim:1}`. See the [`refstyle` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/refstyle) for details.

#### Example

Copy the following code to an empty file and save as a `.lyx` file, e.g. `example.lyx`. Open in LyX and compile. Screenshots of LyX view and PDF below.

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\newref{claim}{name=claim~}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-bytype
theorems-sec-bytype
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Section
Something
\end_layout

\begin_layout Claim
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "claim:claim1"

\end_inset

I hereby claim that I don't use LyX.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Theorem
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "thm:1"

\end_inset

LyX makes some things harder.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Inserting references: 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand formatted
reference "thm:1"

\end_inset

 and 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand formatted
reference "claim:claim1"

\end_inset

.

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions, explicit and implicit! :) I really appreciate your work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the LyX manual, first make sure to check `Use refstyle (not prettyref) ...` in `Document` -> `Settings` -> `Document Class`, and you can put the following in the preamble:

```
\newref{claim}{refcmd={claim \ref{#1}}}
```

Then whenever you refer to a label begin with `claim:` with `Formatted reference` option, you will get the desired format.

I took the liberty of modifying the example lyx file:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\newref{claim}{refcmd={claim \ref{#1}}}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-bytype
theorems-sec-bytype
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Section
Something
\end_layout

\begin_layout Claim
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "claim:1"

\end_inset

I hereby claim that I don't use LyX.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Theorem
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "thm:1"

\end_inset

LyX makes some things harder.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Inserting references: 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand formatted
reference "thm:1"

\end_inset

 and 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand formatted
reference "claim:1"

\end_inset

.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```