# Cross reference in LyX

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lyx

I would like to use the `\autoref` function in LyX, so that when I refer to a labeled figure or theorem, it is typeset as "Figure #" or "Theorem #". According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6063/18228), I can redefine the `\ref` command as `\autoref` using

```
\let\ref\autoref
```

at the beginning of the document. However, this creates a problem: when I refer to an equation, it comes out as "(Equation #)". This is because LyX does not use `\eqref{eq_label}`, but rather `(\ref{eq_label})` to refer to equations.

So my question is: Is there a way to configure LyX so that it uses `\eqref` to refer to equations, and `\autoref` to refer to figures, theorems, etc.

I'm using the `article` document class and MikTeX distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\autoref` is actually simpler and has an nice advantage! The area for clicking on a hyperlink is larger (see example below) since the "type names" are included in the clickable area.

For that, we insert following code in the LyX Preamble.

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\ref\autoref
\renewcommand\equationautorefname{\@gobble}
}
```

The command `\renewcommand\equationautorefname{\@gobble}` is used for equation references to remove the word "Equation~". In the example the styles "Reference" and "(<Reference>)" are used:

[image: lyx document]
[image: output]

Answer (score 5):

Such cross references can be generated in LyX without `\autoref`. LyX uses internally the `refstyle` package. Just change the style for figure, theorem, ... references to "Formatted Reference", and use "(<Reference>)" for equation references. Note that correct label prefixes, e.g., `thm:` or `fig:`, are important. Here is an example (with "hyperref" package support switched on):

[image]

[image]

In this example we also **changed the lower case letters at the beginning of type names to upper case one**, e.g., figure 1 to Figure 1. This is done by modifying the setup of the reference style in `\newref{...}{...}`. We add following to the LyX Preamble:

```
\newref{fig}{%
    name      = \RSFigtxt,  
    names     = \RSFigstxt,
    Name      = \RSFigtxt,
    Names     = \RSFigstxt,
    rngtxt    = \RSrngtxt,
    lsttwotxt = \RSlsttwotxt,
    lsttxt    = \RSlsttxt}
```

If no additional package about reference manipulation are used (e.g., "cleveref") the line `\newref{fig}{name = \RSFigtxt}` might be enough. -- If the "refstyle" package does not know about an environment we need to define a new command additionally. For example, for theorems LyX already provides `\RSthmtxt`. But we add to the LyX Preamble:

```
\def\RSThmtxt{Theorem~}
```

(See also: [Lyx 2.0 Formatted references to theorem/lemma/claim environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62123))

**How to make deeper changes?**

If one writes in a language different from English, one wants references in the native language rather than in English. By default, some translations are available in the "refstyle" package and choosen. Otherwise copy the file "refstyle.cfg" from your TeX tree (probably: "tex/latex/refstyle/refstyle.cfg") to the directory of your “.lyx” file and rename it to “refstyle.def”. You can modify this file to your liking. See ["refstyle" package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/refstyle/refstyle.pdf) (or also [How can I get capitalised cross references in LyX with refstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47134)).

Comment: I've always wondered what the "formatted reference" option is for... Thanks for the enlightenment :)